# why does rsync run through all the files but fail to copy them?

Tags: rsync, backup

I can't fathom why rsync isn't working...

Here's my directory and contents...

```
$ pwd
/home/alec/.dotfiles

$ ls
'~'      neomutt          tmux   vit     gitconfig    mbsyncrc   myclirc              taskrc   tmux.conf        vimrc     zshrc
 drush   remote-servers   vim    ackrc   khard.conf   msmtprc    ptpython_config.py   tigrc    tmuxinator.zsh   xinitrc
```

and here's my backup command...

`rsync -avvr --exclude='view' /home/alec/.dotfiles /media/alec/storage/dotfiles`

After running that command, the destination files are un-changed...

```
$ pwd
/media/alec/storage/dotfiles

$ ls
drush  hiddendrush  vim  gitconfig  tmux.conf  tmuxinator.zsh  vimrc  xinitrc  zshrc
```

I don't know how any more simple it could be.  The `--exclude='view'` is because there's some contents in there that breaks the rsync command and that subdirectory's not needed anyway.  What could be the problem?

When I type the command `rsync` prints to the terminal the entire contents of the source directory, hundreds of files, but they don't get copied to the destination.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the command

```
rsync -avvr --exclude='view' /home/alec/.dotfiles /media/alec/storage/dotfiles
```

This takes the directory `.dotfiles` in `/home/alec` and copies it to directory `/media/alec/storage/dotfiles`, where it becomes `/media/alec/storage/dotfiles/.dotfiles`.  This directory is not shown by `ls` unless you write `ls -A`

The command you want is

```
rsync -avvr --exclude='view' /home/alec/.dotfiles/ /media/alec/storage/dotfiles/
```

Note the addition of two trailing slashes.
This will recursively copy everything in `/home/alec/.dotfiles/` into `/media/alec/storage/dotfiles/`

Comment: Thaaaank youuuuu <3

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your extra directory.

Comment: The slash at the end of the _destination_ path is unimportant. The slash at the end of the _source_ path is important.

Comment: @Kusalananda  True, but probably worth doing anyway.  It does make a difference if you have a single source file.  With the slash, it makes directory and uses the source file's name therein.  Without the slash, it doesn't make a directory and uses the exact name specified.  (It is actually a bit inconsistent.  `rsync -a a b` will make `b/a/...` if `a` is a directory, and just file `b` if `a` is a  file.)